# Has The Doctor ever visited Canada?

Tags: doctor-who

In-universe, the Doctor has visited numerous places on Earth, past, present, and future.

Doctor Who, the production, has on occasion shot on location outside of the U.K. From the original run, "City of Death" featured location scenes in Paris. In the new run, "The Angels Take Manhattan" featured location scenes in New York. Apparently, the 1995-96 movie was co-produced with Canadian involvement and shooting occurred in Vancouver, B.C..

Counting *only* stories which were shot and aired as part of the "official" show, have any stories ever been set in Canada, past, present, or future (even if locations elsewhere stood in)? Apparently, Canada comes up a certain amount, but have scenes played out ostensibly on Canadian soil (even if not actually shot there)?

Comment: Yes, in the novel "Placebo effect"; Sam's other eyebrow raised.'Oh yes? This sounds good.'
'Remember not long after we first met, and I dropped you off at that Greenpeace rally in Canada?'
'Uh-huh.'

Comment: Not counting novels and ["noodle incidents"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident)

Comment: The Doctor's travels on Earth are so limited that I've always wondered if aliens mainly attack only the UK for some reason or whether other parts of the world have their own Timelord protectors.

Comment: @TomHarrington He also spends an awful lot of time on or near Earth. What about the rest of the universe - doesn't that need protecting too?

Answer (score 1):

The 1996 TV movie with Paul McGann was set in the USA, but filmed in Vancouver, and the second page of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_(film)) says it is "to date the only episode of Doctor Who filmed in Canada". The right shot [here](http://www.thedoctorwhosite.co.uk/tardis/exterior/1996-tardis/) from the end of the movie looked like an outdoor shot, but I'm not sure (there's a list of locations [here](http://www.doctorwholocations.net/stories/tvm)). The [Canada article](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Canada) on the TARDIS wikia features various mentions of Canada on the show and in spinoff series, novels, etc., but it doesn't look like any stories on the show were intended to be set in Canada in-universe.

edit: you changed your question, so this answer is somewhat out of date...